# failed to download decoded font Roboto-Regular-webfont

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, css, font-face

Facing issues while downloading the font for the first time(after clearing cache), post reloading for 2/3 times error is not there and font loaded properly.

```
Failed to decode downloaded font: /Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf /Roboto-Bold-webfont.ttf
```

As per research tried few workarounds but still facing the issue

1. tried updating the format('woff') to format('font-woff')
2. tried with absolute url : https://example.com/Roboto-Regular-webfont.ttf

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Oh ho, finally this is not any code issue, this happened because of our internal WAF. waf has blocked such request.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to host the font yourself.

The easiest thing to do is to use the google webfonts helper: https://google-webfonts-helper.herokuapp.com/fonts/roboto?subsets=latin

In your case something like this should be sufficient:

```css
/* roboto-regular - latin */
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Roboto';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url('roboto-v27-latin-regular.eot'); /* IE9 Compat Modes */
  src: local(''),
       url('roboto-v27-latin-regular.eot?#iefix') format('embedded-opentype'), /* IE6-IE8 */
       url('roboto-v27-latin-regular.woff2') format('woff2'), /* Super Modern Browsers */
       url('roboto-v27-latin-regular.woff') format('woff'), /* Modern Browsers */
       url('roboto-v27-latin-regular.ttf') format('truetype'), /* Safari, Android, iOS */
       url('roboto-v27-latin-regular.svg#Roboto') format('svg'); /* Legacy iOS */
}
```

You can download the files from the google-webfonts-helper or directly from google fonts.